# loop data into exsiting object javascript next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So i have an dataset from demoDataset DataGrip as below, i try to loop an action button to the dataset columns as a new field for each row..,

```
{
  "columns": [
    {
      "field": "id",
      "hide": true
    },
    {
      "field": "desk",
      "headerName": "Desk",
      "width": 110,
      "hide": true
    },
    {
      "field": "commodity",
      "headerName": "Commodity",
      "width": 180,
      "editable": false,
      "hide": true
    },
    {
      "field": "traderName",
      "headerName": "Trader Name",
      "width": 120,
      "editable": false,
      "hide": true
    },
    {
      "field": "traderEmail",
      "headerName": "Trader Email",
      "width": 150,
      "editable": false,
      "hide": true
    },
    {
      "field": "quantity",
      "headerName": "Quantity",
      "type": "number",
      "width": 140,
      "editable": false,
      "hide": true
    },
    {
      "field": "filledQuantity",
      "headerName": "Filled Quantity",
      "availableAggregationFunctions": [
        "min",
        "max",
        "avg",
        "size"
      ],
      "type": "number",
      "width": 120,
      "editable": false,
      "hide": true
    },
    {
      "field": "isFilled",
      "headerName": "Is Filled",
      "align": "center",
      "type": "boolean",
      "width": 80,
      "editable": false,
      "hide": true
    },
    {
      "field": "status",
      "headerName": "Status",
      "type": "singleSelect",
      "valueOptions": [
        "Open",
        "PartiallyFilled",
        "Filled",
        "Rejected"
      ],
      "width": 150,
      "editable": false,
      "hide": true
    },
    {
      "field": "unitPrice",
      "headerName": "Unit Price",
      "type": "number",
      "editable": false,
      "hide": true
        }, etc....
}
```

i have an new field object button to push in to the array of "columns" but it keeps returning me an error here is my code:

```
const button = {
  field: "Print",
  renderCell: (cellValues) => {
    return (
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={(event) => {
          handleClick(event, cellValues);
        }}
      >
        Edit
      </Button>
    );
  },
};
const dataNew = data.columns.map((col) => {
    return { Button, ...col };
  });
```

here is the error

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Call Stack
eval
node_modules\@mui\x-data-grid\hooks\features\rows\useGridRows.js (426:50)
commitHookEffectListMount
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22969:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (24702:0)
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (24666:0)
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin
```

i dont see something wrong here as i already pass the value of the rest data using ..col

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code using codesandbox or other similar websites. As far as I can tell `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')` means you are accessing the `length` property on a variable which is not defined.

Comment: it shows an error when i push the button object to the data.columns as below: TypeError: Cannot add property 36, object is not extensible

Comment: Button is a react component, you are trying to merge a React component and a object

Comment: solved, i am using material UI